# Betta with other fish... a fight? or other cause?

Tags: fish, aquarium

I have very small tank, and it's my 4th or 5th month that i own a beta (fighter) fish. last day i went to store to change the pipe, that i see those fish, i don't know all of their names, and some in english so i have to describe or show image, ...

i bought a black ghost knife, one of those small cleaner (i think is a plecos), two triangular one that are in the image, and two glass cleaner (as it was wrote in my language) which stick to walls or ground, and 5 very small fish, and 2 apple snail, a gold and a brown one. i though next month upgrade my tank to a big one two, but this morning i notice the watter is so messy, i though maybe the food were too much, or they dirty the watter as they are now too many, but once i back, there were only the beta, plecos, and those 5 small which i don't know their names, including two snail...
know i want to know if the snail are poisnous, or the beta hit them hard... what should i do? 
I really missed the black ghost knife
[image]
[image]
[image]

i want to make sure what do i do the next time i went to that store... i liked these fishes that i take, so i think i go for same type the next time too...

also if it were beta, on the time of night which i didn't noticed, would it hit my other small too? or i can leave them in this tank together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be a very small, novelty-sized aquarium (1-3 gallons?). The recommended size for a *single* beta fish is at least 5 gallons (preferably 10 gallons)… so **that tank looks *fatally* overcrowded.**

Those 8 cm (3") Plecos will grow into  30-60 cm (1-2 foot) long fish that need a very large aquarium to do well. That Silver Angel will also get as big as your outstretched hand. Snails are also messy (and can also be aggressive "fish suckers"), so a big guy like that isn't recommended for a small tank either.

**Beta fish are also EXTREMELY territorial,** so it is generally recommended you keep them alone. *Some* beta fish (on a case-by-case basis) ***may*** tolerate a tank mate if that fish is "dull" and somewhat unobtrusive. But any fish with colorful scales or other showy displays will almost certainly provoke attacks and constant harassment causing injury or possibly death to the other fish.

I'm sorry to say that a larger tank isn't really a solution here. To keep all those fish, you should get a 2nd tank.

Comment: which fish i can afford from what i had to put beside betta? is he cause of death of all of them, or some died for dirty water?

Comment: can they live a month so i buy a tank next month? or should i do it very fast? i though plecos are aquarium washer, but i hear they have too many waste that dirty the water... i have small filter, can it keep the water clean? or should i still replace the water? about snail, i hear they put their eggs on the ground and it should be much higher than the water level, ... also they need protection, can i split the next tank with sand, and lead the child to other side? i think i go for 40 gallone, as they are too expensive toward our earning in my country. and should i buy real plant

Comment: @deadManN Unfortunately, it would be very difficult to diagnose why a fish has died from your description and pictures. If fish are dying, I would suggest doing something sooner rather than waiting a month. I recommend bringing a water sample from your tank to your local aquarium shop to test for problems. You can describe your setup and what fish you have (bring the pictures) so they can recommend a setup for the fish that remain. Good luck!

Comment: something like pets, doesn't work the way that a pet shop be really expert, they just own fish, and they sell it, even if there are some, i have no friend to ask, and i didn't found on the internet in my city... but i'll create a new Topic to discuss about the way that i should handle the water. the seller how i bough the ship from didn't look the worse shop around but still, he gave the wrong guidance. also i saw someone had two beta with those triangle shaped, not sure if they were exact same kind, but those beta only attacked each other, and each one stood i a side, but no attack to other.